# problem with port 587 how enable this for send email

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, smtp, firewall, mailkit

hi I'm trying send email , but I just get this error :

```
an attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden.
```

I'm using `smtp.gmail.com`

I search about this and I find it's bc firewall don't allow to use port 587

I tried to add `Inbound rules` in firewall , but did not answer.

so anyone know how can enable port 587 to send email ???

if need send image about anything pls tell me .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are calling from your application to the gmail server. That would be an outbound rule so you need to add a outbound exception to the firewall.

Comment: If you don't care what the server is and only need it for dev, I highly recommend this https://github.com/ChangemakerStudios/Papercut-SMTP

Comment: thanks i will go search how add outbound 
"thanks"